# AT&T assembly + C functions. Using Scanf for string input

Tags: c, function, assembly, scanf

I'm trying to use scanf in assembly to get input. 
As I know I have to push on stack arguments of functions in reverse order and then call function. It works fine with printf function but something is not quite right with scanf and place for input. Scanf should have 2 arguments. 1st is type of input (string,int, char etc) and 2nd is adress where to put it.

```
scanf(„%s” , buffer)
```

Is our goal i think.
My code:

```
.data 

name: .ascii "What is your name?\n"
name2: .ascii "Your name is:"
formatScanf: .ascii "%s"
.bss
buffer: .size 100 #100 bytes for string input

.text 
.globl main 
main: 

#Printing question #works fine
pushl $name       
call printf 

#Get answers
push $buffer    #2nd argument for scanf
push $formatScanf #1st argument of scanf
call scanf



#Exiting
pushl $0 
call exit
```

Error message:

```
lab3.s: Assembler messages:
lab3.s:8: Error: expected comma after name `' in .size directive
```

As compiler i'm using gcc with : " gcc -m32 Program.s -o run" command to have 32bit procesor work type, and to have C libuary linked automaticly.

What is wrong with it?
How should i use scanf in asm?

EDIT:
I should have used use .space not .size  or .size buffer, 100
It compiles now.

EDIT 2:
COMPLETE CODE WITH USING SCANF C FUNCTION

```
#printf proba
.data 


name2: .string "Your name is: %s "
formatScanf: .string "%s"
name: .string "What is your name?\n"
.bss
buffer: .space 100

.text 
.globl main 
main: 

#Printing question #works fine
pushl $name       
call printf 

#Get answers
push $buffer    #2nd argument for scanf
push $formatScanf #1st argument of scanf
call scanf

push $buffer
push $name2
call printf

#Exiting
pushl $0 
call exit
```

Comment: The `.size` directive does not do what you think it does.  Refer to the assembler manual for details.

Comment: Well, i wanted 100 bytes of 0 to write there a string. 

".space size , fill
This directive emits size bytes, each of value fill. Both size and fill are absolute expressions. If the comma and fill are omitted, fill is assumed to be zero. This is the same as ‘.skip’."

Comment: Yes, that would be correct.  However, you wrote `.size` instead of `.space`.  Is this whole question just a typo?

Comment: I'm so blind. Ok gonna check it out

Comment: Another problem is the calling convention. Your compiler does not necessarily pass the arguments to the function (including the variadic ones) via the stack (or at least not all of them).

Comment: @PeterJ_01 On i686 UNIX it does so, unless you manually specify a different calling convention.  stdcall vs. cdecl could be an issue, but I don't see any symbol decoration, so I assume this is UNIX where everything is cdecl.

Comment: It almost works. 
I have other problem now with pushing arguments on stack. I'm trying to push : 
push $buffer
push $name2
call printf

and it gives me:
Your name is: "input from console" Which is fine
But then it gives me string from "name" label. so it is 
Your name is: FenrirWhat is your name?

Comment: @Fenrir That's cause you forgot to terminate your strings.  An easy fix is to use `.string` instead of `.ascii`.  Refer to the manual for details.

Comment: It works fine. I will add complete code for anyone who wants to see how to do it. I haven't seen example in At&t.
Fuz thank you for help again. I hope you have great day :D

Comment: @fuz is it possible to pass to printf 2 arguments? int and string?
I wanted to do : " name2: .string "Your name is: %s . And you are %d years old " but when i get %d it make very strange number. Code on https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/192215/assembly-with-c-functions-printf-and-scanf

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the GNU assembler, the `.size` directive specifies the size of a symbol.  This is merely for informal purposes and has no effect whatsoever on the program.  Most importantly, it does not specify the size of a buffer or variable or whatever.

In the GNU assembler, there is no notion of variable size or similar.  To create a buffer of desired length, assemble the desired number of blank bytes and tack a label in front, like this:

```
buffer: .space 100
```

The `.space` directive assembles the given number of NUL bytes into the object.  Optionally, you should afterwards set a symbol size for `buffer` so the output of `nm -S` is meaningful:

```
.size buffer, 100
```

Leaving this out won't hurt you, but then `nm -S` won't show size data for your symbol and doing so might make certain debug utilities less effective.